# Error handling using aspects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I see myself handling similar exceptions in a rather similar fashion repeatedly and would like to use aspects to keep this error handling code outside of the core business logic. A quick search online pulled up a couple of ruby gems (aquarium, aspector, etc) but I don't see a whole lot of downloads for those gems in rubygems. Given that, I want to believe there are probably other nicer ways to deal with this in Ruby.

```
get '/products/:id' do
  begin
    product = find_product params[:id]
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    status 404
  end
end

get '/users/:id' do
  begin
    user = find_user params[:id]
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    status 404
  end
end
```

In the above example, there are 2 Sinatra routes that look for a requested object by ID in MongoDB and throw a 404 if the object were not to be found. Clearly, the code is repetitive and I am looking to find a Ruby way to make it DRY.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see answer in [this](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Error%20Handling) guide.

You code example:

`error Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound do
  status 404
end`